# Quadratic programming in Pyodide

Tags: python, quadratic-programming, pyodide

I would like to know if there is any library, which I can use in Pyodide and which has a function, similar to "quadprog" in Matlab or multiple external libraries in Python ([McGibbon's quadprog](https://pypi.org/project/quadprog/), [CVXOPT](https://cvxopt.org/) etc.) doing quadratic optimization over convex polytopes. I found some optimization packages among the [packages directory](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide/tree/main/packages) of Pyodide, however they do not implement quadratic programming specifically.
Also there is a javascript [qp library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quadprog-js), but I am not sure that it will be possible to make it work with Pyodide.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Yes, currently there is no such package, but feel free to add for instance quadprog to Pyodide packages via a PR on Github. It looks significantly easier to build than CVXOPT. 

About the qp library,  it's likely possible to use it to some extent via type translations in Pyodide, but it would be easier (and probably faster) to have a corresponding Python package.

Comment: Dear rth, thanks for the answer! I am not sure if it is possible to add quadprog to Pyodide , since quadprog is based on c code, which is used via cython: https://github.com/quadprog/quadprog/tree/master/quadprog
If someone can confirm whether this is a problem or not, please let me know.

Comment: It should be fine. We have other packages with C & Cython in Pyodide.